Bound and Unbound types in C#
Bound and Unbound types in C#

The term unbound type refers to a non-generic type or an unbound generic type. The term bound type refers to a non-generic type or a constructed type.

What does an unbound type in C# mean? And why are non-generic types unbound types?
Need help in understanding bound and unbound types in C#.
